# Mvp.Xsl calling C# scripts

Tags: c#, xslt, exslt

I'm using Mvp.Xsl implementation of EXSLT. I'm trying to call C# script in my XSLT template. It works when processing with XslCompiledTransform, but not with Mvp.Xsl. I get following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it.
```

I understand this error when processing with XslCompiled transform, I can get rid of it using XsltSettings:

```
System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings.Default.EnableScript = true;
```

But this does not work for Mvp.Xsl and I have not found similar setting. Is it even possible to call C# scripts when using Mvp.Xsl?

Thanks a lot,
Petr

Comment: write an email to Oleg Tkachenko. As I said earlier, it feels masochistic not to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Dimitre: thanks a lot for suggestion, I sent him an email with this question.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT scripting should be enabled only if you require script support and you are working in a fully trusted environment.

The following code loads a style sheet and enables XSLT script support.

```
// Create the XsltSettings object with script enabled.
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false,true);

// Create the XslCompiledTransform object and load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("sample.xsl", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```